# Browse Button in VS 2012 Ultimate not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ide

Please help, I just installed a fresh copy of VS 2012 Ultimate and tried to create a new project for the first time, and the **Browse...** button in the New Project Window is working fine.

After that, the next thing I only did is to change the theme from "Light" to "Dark". After that, I restarted my laptop.

Now, I tried to create a new project again (File > New Project), the **Browse...** button is not working again. I tried to type the directory manually and I was able to create my project to the directory of my choice, but then, when I added a Picture object and want to set an image for that, the Browse button in the object is not working as well.

Please note that even I tried to choose a different project types (C# or VB.net), the Browser button is not working at all. VS 2012 is not freezing and responding just fine except for the Browse button.

I already tried the following known fixes, but still no good:

- Right click -> Customize, select the 'Commands' tab. Select Toolbar: Standard then hit 'Reset All'
- Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset
- Repair under the Program Window > Change > Repair
- Run devenv.exe /safemode
- Reinstall VS 2012, still no good

Please help, I need it to for my work... Note: I just reformat my OS (Win7 Ultimate)

Comment: It sounds like an os issue, but you could try running a VS repair...

Comment: I already tried VS repair, still no good. If it is an OS issue, I just reformat my laptop with Win7 Ultimate. I'm trying to reinstall VS 2012 at the moment.. I hope this will fix the problem..

Comment: Could be a bad format 

Comment: All of my other tools are working good, just done reinstalling VS 2012. Still no good.

Comment: Have you tried 2013?

Comment: I'm planning to use 2013, but the minimum OS is Win8 (which is a conflict with my current OS: Win7 Ultimate). I guess I'll try VS 2010.

Comment: Where dis you get that from? VS 2013 fully supports Win7, and Vista! VS 2015 will support Win7.. Do you have a link for that misinformation so I can go get it fixed?

Comment: I installed VS 2013, but it prompted me that my OS is not compatible and it should be at least Win8. I got the VS 2013 from Microsoft via download. My boss gave me another copy of Win7 with SP1 (without the hassle of downloading the SP1) and I'm about to try it again. I'll post here again if there's any changes *fingers crossed*

Answer (score 1):

Though its an old topic but no answer was posted. I was having same issue on the Visual Studio 2012. I resolved it by following these steps.

- Go To `Services`
- Activate `Tablet PC Input Service`
- Restart Visual Studio

Browse button should work after these steps.

Comment: Thanks, You save the day.